# Google Streetview API overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-street-view

Does anyone know if I can draw georeferenced polygons in the streetview api. I'm curious to know if anyone has successfully tried this. I see that custom overlays are allowed but I'm not sure if this includes polygons, shapefiles, or tiled map caches.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays

Comment: From the documentation:  "Currently, the types of overlays which are supported on Street View panoramas are limited to Markers, InfoWindows and custom OverlayViews. "

Comment: images can be placed http://projects.teammaps.com/projects/streetviewoverlay/streetviewoverlay.htm

Comment: @Mapperz you should make this comment into an answer. Its a good example and helped me figure out how to do some image overlays - even though it was a bit more crude than what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1634292 done as requested. glad it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometries especially polygons will be are to place in Streetview mode (Earth API would be better).

**But Images can be overlayed into streetview**

This simple demo shows how to display an image overlay over a streetview and sync its movement (approximately) as the street view POV (point of view) changes

This source is available from 'http://teammaps.com/'

http://projects.teammaps.com/projects/streetviewoverlay/streetviewoverlay.htm

```
var svo = null;

// the main application object
function SVO()
{
    // Trafalgar Square
    this.lat = 51.507768;
    this.lng = -0.127957;
    this.zoom = 16;

    this.slat = 51.507527;
    this.slng = -0.128652;

    this.image = "img/slidecat.gif";

    this.pt = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
    this.streetPt = new google.maps.LatLng(this.slat, this.slng);

    // initial POV
    this.sheading = 69.58;
    this.spitch = 0;
    this.szoom = 1;

    this.distance = 0;  // distance in metres from street view to marker
    this.maximumDistance = 200;     // distance beyond which marker is hidden

    // dimensions of street view container (fixed)
    this.panWidth = 480;
    this.panHeight = 480;

    // dimensions of marker container (resized according to current pov)
    this.markerWidth = 120;
    this.markerHeight = 80;
}


// create map
SVO.prototype.m_initMap = function ()
{
    var mapDiv = eid("mapDiv");

    var mapOptions =
    {
        center: this.pt,
        zoom: this.zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
}


// create street view
SVO.prototype.m_initPanorama = function ()
{
    var visible = false;
    var l_panDiv = eid("panDiv");

    // controls can be hidden here to prevent the position being changed by the user
    var l_panOptions =
    {
        // zoomControl: false,
        // linksControl: false
    };

    l_panOptions.position = this.streetPt;
    l_panOptions.pov =
    {
        heading: this.sheading,
        pitch: this.spitch,
        zoom: this.szoom
    };

    pan = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(l_panDiv, l_panOptions);

    map.setStreetView(pan);

    // event handlers    
    google.maps.event.addListener(pan, 'pov_changed', function ()
    {
        svo.m_updateMarker();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(pan, 'zoom_changed', function ()
    {
        svo.m_updateMarker();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(pan, 'position_changed', function ()
    {
        svo.streetPt = pan.getPosition();
        map.setCenter(svo.streetPt);

        svo.m_updateMarker();
    });

}




function Marker(p_name, p_icon, p)
{
    this.m_icon = "";

    this.pt = null;
    this.m_pov = null;

    this.m_pixelpt = null;
}

// convert the current heading and pitch (degrees) into pixel coordinates
SVO.prototype.m_convertPointProjection = function (p_pov, p_zoom)
{
    var l_fovAngleHorizontal = 90 / p_zoom;
    var l_fovAngleVertical = 90 / p_zoom;

    var l_midX = this.panWidth / 2;
    var l_midY = this.panHeight / 2;

    var l_diffHeading = this.sheading - p_pov.heading;
    l_diffHeading = normalizeAngle(l_diffHeading);
    l_diffHeading /= l_fovAngleHorizontal;

    var l_diffPitch = (p_pov.pitch - this.spitch) / l_fovAngleVertical;

    var x = l_midX + l_diffHeading * this.panWidth;
    var y = l_midY + l_diffPitch * this.panHeight;

    var l_point = new google.maps.Point(x, y);

    return l_point;
}

// create the 'marker' (a div containing an image which can be clicked)
SVO.prototype.m_initMarker = function ()
{
    var l_markerDiv = eid("markerDiv");
    l_markerDiv.style.width = this.markerWidth + "px";
    l_markerDiv.style.height = this.markerHeight + "px";

    var l_iconDiv = eid("markerDiv");
    l_iconDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.image + "' width='100%' height='100%' alt='' />";

    this.m_updateMarker();
}

SVO.prototype.m_updateMarker = function ()
{
    var l_pov = pan.getPov();
    if (l_pov)
    {
        var l_zoom = pan.getZoom();

        // scale according to street view zoom level
        var l_adjustedZoom = Math.pow(2, l_zoom) / 2;


        // recalulate icon heading and pitch now
        this.sheading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(this.streetPt, this.pt)
        this.distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.streetPt, this.pt);

        var l_pixelPoint = this.m_convertPointProjection(l_pov, l_adjustedZoom);

        var l_markerDiv = eid("markerDiv");


        var l_distanceScale = 50 / this.distance;
        l_adjustedZoom = l_adjustedZoom * l_distanceScale;

        // _TODO scale marker according to distance from view point to marker 
        // beyond maximum range a marker will not be visible

        // apply position and size to the marker div
        var wd = this.markerWidth * l_adjustedZoom;
        var ht = this.markerHeight * l_adjustedZoom;

        var x = l_pixelPoint.x - Math.floor(wd / 2);
        var y = l_pixelPoint.y - Math.floor(ht / 2);

        l_markerDiv.style.display = "block";
        l_markerDiv.style.left = x + "px";
        l_markerDiv.style.top = y + "px";
        l_markerDiv.style.width = wd + "px";
        l_markerDiv.style.height = ht + "px";


        // hide marker when its beyond the maximum distance
        l_markerDiv.style.display = this.distance < this.maximumDistance ? "block" : "none";
        // glog("distance = " + Math.floor(this.distance) + " m (" + l_markerDiv.style.display + ") distance scale = " + l_distanceScale + " l_adjustedZoom = " + l_adjustedZoom);

        eid("markerInfo").innerHTML = "lat: " + formatFloat(this.streetPt.lat(), 6) + " lng: " + formatFloat(this.streetPt.lng(), 6) + " distance: " + Math.floor(this.distance) + " m";
    }
}

// display a message when the user clicks on the marker's div
function markerClick()
{
    eid("markerInfo").innerHTML = "<h2>Meow !!!</h2>";
}



function loadPage()
{
    svo = new SVO();
    svo.m_initMap();
    svo.m_initPanorama();
    svo.m_initMarker();
}


// utils
function eid(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function glog(a)
{
    if (typeof (console) != "undefined" && console && console.log)
    {
        console.log(a);
    }
}


function formatFloat(n, d)
{
    var m = Math.pow(10, d);
    return Math.round(n * m, 10) / m;
}


function normalizeAngle(a)
{

    while (a > 180)
    {
        a -= 360;
    }

    while (a < -180)
    {
        a += 360;
    }

    return a;
}
```